# Discrepancy between Transactional annotation on a Business function and DAO it uses

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactionmanager

I've come across the following setup:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- connection string to read-write instance -->
</bean>



<bean id="roTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="roHibernateSessionFactory" />
    <qualifier value="readOnly" />
</bean>

<bean id="roHibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="roDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="roDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- connection string to read-only instance -->
</bean>
```

The beans with "ro" prefix are basically built to allow us to connect to a readonly instance of the database.

Then I came across this piece of code in which we are using the Transaction Manager that's supposed to give us hibernate sessions connected to the readonly instance while using the DAO bean that's injected with the read-write data source.

```
<bean id="readWriteDao" class="com.services.dao.ReadWriteDao" scope="singleton">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>

@Transactional(value = "readOnly", propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS,
        readOnly = true)
public List<MyItem> findItems(List<Long> itemIds) {
    return  readWriteDao.findItems(itemIds);
}
```

My questions are:

1. Which instance is this code using?
2. How would I validate that through logging?

Comment: What's the scope/lifetime of the bean with the `findItems`, i.e. in which context is that method executed?

Comment: It's a singleton bean if that's what you mean and is injected to a Web Service's implementation class.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in your bean declaration it uses the "hibernateSessionFactory".

(I would not know how the application reacts if you load an entity via a readonly sessionfactory and save it through the other sessionfactory as these objects would never be in the write session. Interesting approach ;) )

Comment: Could you please explain how you came to that conclusion? And also please answer my 2nd question?

This is a mistake by the way. I wouldn't think the application should be doing this.